# Abstract and Inheritance. the output comes out incorrectly

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

If anyone else is having problems this  type of problem. Im leaving my post up for you.

I am having some trouble with abstract and Inheritance.

My code is suppose to output asterisks in form of a rectangle, triangle, and a parallelogram.

The problem is that the triangle and parallelogram are coming out as boxes.

If some one can help me find the problem and explain why it happen.

Paralelogram

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESpBp.png)public String toString()

```
{
    String output = "";

for (int i = 0; i < mHeight; i++)

{
        for (int j = 0; j < mPbase+ i; j++)

{ 
          output += "* ";


}

        output += "\n";
        for (int l = 0; l <= i; l++) 
        {
            output += " ";
        }

    }
    output += "The area of this Pall is "  + calculatedArea() + " square 
units.";
    return output;
```

Comment: So, you want the same code to print different forms?

Comment: Welcome ... and although your question contains all the necessary information, I think you will have a hard time getting helpful responses. You see, you put down **a lot** of code. People would have to download then run it, then debug it. Most likely, that is not going to happen. From that point of view, the best I have for you A) either add *trace* print statements or B) learn how to use a debugger , like ...

Comment: ... http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html  yourself. Maybe somebody finds the time and energy to debug this for you, but I rather doubt it. And honestly: at some point you should learn how to do that yourself anyway. Because it is an essential part of being a developer. So you can as well start learning today.

Comment: It is mostly the for loops that giving me a hard time

Comment: This question has been asked many, many, many times here before, and there are even lots of answers already. My advice is break down your code to the part you don't understand and just work with that. Think about the smallest chunk of code that will make a line of chars. Now think how you might combine successive calls to that code to make a basic shape. Extend this to general rules for making specific shapes. SO is really a terrible debugger. Now is the best time to learn debugging yourself. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in you are looping over the width and height, you aren't calculating the width for that layer. If I have a width of 5 and a height of 5, doing a standard double for loop will just give me a 5x5. Instead try subtracting the height index from the width for the inner for loop. For the Triangle this will at least print out an upside down triangle

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String output = "";

    for (int i = 1; i <= mHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= mTbase - i; j++) {
            output += "* ";
        }
        output += "\n";
    }
    output += "The area of this triangle is " + calculatedArea() + " square 
units.";
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for spending a bit of your time my problem. your answer helped my greatly and was a huge hint for the Parallelogram.